# Run Counter Strike in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: games, steam

I'm a huge fan of Counter Strike. I have Ubuntu 15.10 and I want to install Counter Strike on it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Counter strike is available on `steam`

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Just search for it, if you already own it on Windows, you own it for Ubuntu too.

[image]

Comment: If this answer helped you, please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't buy CS, you can download "Warzone" CS and install. To do that, you will need to install "wine"

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

After the wine installation, you will be able to run "exe" the setup files you have.

PS: I support buying games

Comment: Help me buy a game.
Because I have heard that the wine makes the system slow by high memory consumption

Comment: Sorry, I am in no position to help with that buying. If you have card or if you can get help from your relatives to buy some bundle packs or wallet code when sales are on, it will be great for you. I use wine to play CS1.6 sometimes though I have Steam CS too and it is not that pain to my PC.